# Memory leak identified for NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

When i run the instrument i got memory link in below line

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest 
    returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```

Can some one explain me how to fix this issue,

Thanks
Sam.

```
- (NSString *)sendHttpsReq:(NSString *) urlString {

     // create the request 
     NSString *endResult = nil;

     NSURL *posHostUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
     NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:posHostUrl
                 cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed
                timeoutInterval:300.0];
     // create the connection with the request
     // and start loading the data 
     [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[posHostUrl host]];

     NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];


     if (theConnection) {
      // Create the NSMutableData that will hold
      // the received data
      // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere 


      NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
      //NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init]; 
      NSError *error  = nil;  
      NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

      endResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
            //[error release];

     } else{
      //Inform the user that the connection failed.
      NSLog(@"CONNECTION FAILED");
     }

     [theConnection release];

     return [endResult autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in fact starting **two** NSURLConnections. One asynchronous and one synchronous. This could possible lead to the leak.

First URLConnection is started in the line:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Second URLConnection is started in the line:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```

Please make sure you only download your resource once.